# how to findIndex of

Tags: javascript, indexing

I'm wondering how to get the findindex of a specific service_name in the below array?

```
var obj = {"ID":111222,"NAME":"Chicken","FREQUENCY":"Yearly","service_name":["Open ticket","Service Account time","Assets Management Overview"]}
```

I have tried the following but not getting the correct index

```
var find_index = obj.service_name.findIndex(function(obj){return obj.service_name = "Open ticket"})
console.log ("The index of " + find_index);
```

Comment: Thats an object mate not array ;)

Comment: @Tushar `obj.service_name` is an array

Comment: `.indexOf( "Open ticket" )` returns 0

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof_array.asp might be what you are looking for.

Comment: @ExplosionPills: Why did you re-open this? This is an obvious dupe. Also, typo's have their own close reason.

Comment: @Cerbrus You can use `indexOf`, but [`findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) is a valid array method. He is properly calling `.findIndex` on the array as in `obj.service_name.findIndex`. There are a couple of other issues with his code, but he has a valid attempt here -- hence the question.

Comment: @ExplosionPills that is debatable.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your code is close, but there are a couple of semantic issues. You're already iterating over the `service_name` array so the argument that the `.findIndex` callback takes is the array element / string itself. You also need to use `==` or `===` for comparison. Right now you are performing assignment.

```
const find_index = obj.service_name.findIndex(
  serviceName => "Open ticket" === serviceName
);
```

In this case you can also use `.indexOf` which would be a bit simpler:

```
const index = obj.service_name.indexOf("Open ticket");
```

Comment: Thanks @Explosion Pills I ended up using the `indexOf` approach.